# EXCEL: what is the formula for getting the time remaining until tonight 00:00

Tags: excel

I have a list of date and time, say 3/5/2018 15:00:00
I want a formula to calculate the time remaining until tonight 00:00
for this example, it should be 09:00:00

[this is an image of the resulting table I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jokmG.png)

what i tried: =TEXT(TIME(24,0,0)-A20, "hh:mm")  the result is #Value!

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The general algorithm for this, in any programming language or environment is simple:

1. Get the `date` component from the `date-time` value.
2. Increment the day value.
3. Subtract the `date-time` value from the `date` value in step 2

   - This works because the value from step 2 is still a `date-time` value, but the time-of-day component is now zero which represents that day's morning-midnight (i.e. `00:00` in the 24-hour clock).

In Excel, `date`, `time`, and `date-time` values are all represented by decimal numbers where the integer component represents a day-count after some epoch and fractional component represents the time-of-day.

- This means step 1 is done by simply doing `INT( date-time-value )`.
- And step 2 is done by simply adding `+1` to that value.
- And step 3 is simple subtraction, but be sure to set the cell's display format to "Time" and not Date or Date-Time.

Cell `B2` should have this formula:

```
=( INT( A2 ) + 1 ) - A2
```

Then drag-fill that for the column to get the values for the other rows.

That's it.

Comment: I was thinking of using CEILING or ROUNDUP but I like the maths.

Answer (score 1):

So, did this, do note that my answer is in decimals... You can sort to hours, minutes and seconds...

```
=24-(HOUR(B4)+MINUTE(B4)/60+SECOND(B4)/3600)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
=24-TEXT(A20,"hh:mm")
```

Considering midnight is either 0 or 24, depending on where you come from, as we are moving towards it we consider as "24" and when we are moving from it, "0". So I subtract the current time/date in a format that excludes the date from "24" and there you have remaining time to midnight.
Do not forget to format the cell to "time", otherwise the results will be wrong.

Comment: Maybe abs(0-TEXT(A20,"hh:mm"))